# PayPal JS SDK Checkout : fetch returns error 500 when switching from sandbox to live

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

The PayPal JS SDK works fine in sandbox mode, but in Live I keep receiving a 500 error.

I am successfully authorizing credit card payments using the SDK but an error message in https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxfunding=credit,card&currency=MYR

```
throw new Error("Promise serialization is not implemented; nothing to deserialize")
```

I followed the PayPal guide and really can not see my mistake here:

```
public function paypal_capture()
{
       $gateway_data = $this->billing->gateway(4);

        $orderId = $this->input->post('orderID', true);
        $itype = $this->input->post('itype', true);


      $clientId =$gateway_data['key1']; //$paypal_conf['client_id'];
    $clientSecret =$gateway_data['key2'];//$paypal_conf['secret'];

       if($gateway_data['dev_mode'] == true)
    {
        $environment = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);

    } else {
         $environment = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\ProductionEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
    }

     $client = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient($environment);

     $request = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCaptureRequest($orderId);
     $request->prefer('return=representation');
     try {

         $response = $client->execute($request);

           echo json_encode($response);

         $response = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);

         if (isset($response['result']) and $response['result']['intent'] == 'CAPTURE' and $response['result']['status'] == 'COMPLETED') {

             $note = 'INV '.$response['result']['purchase_units'][0]['reference_id'].' Paypal Payment #' . $response['result']['id'];




             $this->billing->paynow($response['result']['purchase_units'][0]['reference_id'],  $response['result']['purchase_units'][0]['amount']['value'], $note, 'Card',$itype);

         }
     }
      catch (HttpException $ex) {

         echo json_encode(array('status'=>'Error','message'=>'Code '.$ex->statusCode.' Contact to seller.'));

     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In the PHP: `if($gateway_data['dev_mode'] == true)` -- have you set this to `false`, as well as changing the clientId and secret to be from an application from the "Live" tab of https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications ?

Comment: OMG can't believe i have overlooked on the if($gateway_data['dev_mode'] == true) set to false everything works fine. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP...

```php
if($gateway_data['dev_mode'] == true)
```

..ensure this configured value is set to `false` so that the code communicates with the PayPal live/production endpoints, as well as changing the clientId and secret to be from the an application from the "Live" tab of [My Apps & Credentials](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications)